# Validate User Input I don't want it to start over when I say no after putting in the wrong input

Tags: python

I am trying to validate a users input by using while True:

When I type the wrong input it tells the user invalid, but when I say no I don't want to continue the code still start's over when I want it to exit the program. How would I fix this?

## Output text to the console

```
def play_again():
    print("")
    incorrect = ""
    while incorrect != "yes" and incorrect != "no":
        incorrect = input("Not a valid entry.\n"
                          "Please choose yes or no:\n").lower()
        if "y" in incorrect:
            break
        elif "n" in incorrect:
            break
    return incorrect
    


while True:
    print("")
    intro()
# Output text to the console
    print("")
    make_choice()

    accept = input("would you like to play again? \n"
                   "Type yes or no: ").lower()
    if 'n' in accept:
        print_pause("Thanks for playing!")
        break
    elif 'y' in accept:
        print_pause("Awsome! Lets play again.")
    else:
        play_again()
```

Comment: Does your `"Thanks for playing!"` message get printed when you say 'no'?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It instantly starts over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the logic should be in the `play_again` function. It can return `True` if the user wants to play again, else `False`.

```
def play_again():
    accept = input("would you like to play again?\nType yes or no: ").lower()
    while True:
        if accept in ["y", "yes"]:
            print_pause("Awesome! Lets play again.")
            return True
        elif accept in ["n", "no"]:
            print_pause("Thanks for playing!")
            return False
        accept = input("Not a valid entry.\nPlease choose yes or no:\n").lower()

while True:
    print("")
    intro()
    print("")
    make_choice()
    if not play_again():
        break
```